# AS Level Decision mathematics (D1) problem

Tags: decision-theory

I've been doing the past papers of my D1 decision mathematics module and I came across a question I couldn't do. The question is part D of the below. I'm not sure how to tackle it as usually you turn the problem into some sort of equality and use that as your constraint, then use the constraints to create your objective function...but how can I get this objective function in the form they want?

(The paper is the D1 paper from January 2010 [$\textit{Don't know exam board - Nethesis}$] for if you want to look at the mark-scheme.)

For clarification, D1 is a module taken by some UK students at ages 16-18 as part of AS levels.

[The paper in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idyru.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, what do you find weird about it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to tackle the question. So usually with these questions you put it into an eqaulity and then proceed but its asking for an objective function

Comment: I had rejected the edit suggested by @Vinicius Rodrigues, as it undid the clarification added by the OP. But I'd still like to thank him for fixing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you want to maximise the total space you have, and large cupboards ($y$) have 40% more space than standard cupboards ($x$). If you say that for each $x$ you get 1 unit of space, then for each $y$ you get 1.4. Thus to maximise space you maximise $x+1.4y$ because $x+1.4y$ is how many units of space you have. Multiply by 5 and you get $5x+1.4y$.

So: If each $x$ has 5 units of space, then as $y=1.4x$, each $y$ gives 7 units of space. Thus to maximise space I maximise $5x+7y$.

Btw I'm disappointed with those of you who have down voted this. I'll admit D1 isn't exactly the most advanced topic, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't answer a question if we can.

Comment: (Out of curiosity, *what* is "D1"?)

Comment: @ClementC. It's an AS level maths module you have the option of taking if you choose maths in the UK. It's usually taken when you're 16-17, but sometimes because you have to get so many modules to get a grade you'll do it at 18. It's a bit of a useless module tbh, and embodies that hated procedure based maths you do before uni.

Comment: Just to add that this was the Edexcel Exam Board just incase anyone else is looking for it. @Nethesis You sir are my knight in shining armor, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Say that the volume of a normal cupboard is $a> 0$ (this is a constant). Can you write the total volume obtained with $x$ standard cupboards and $y$ large cupboards as a function of $x,y$ and $a$? (Call that $V(x,y,a)$.) Now, you want to find $x,y$ which maximize $V(x,y,a)$. Observing that $a$ is a constant, can you show (given the expression you got for $V(x,y,a)$) that this is equivalent to maximizing $5x+7y$?